# How to dispose Toastbar message when navigating to different form before timeout occurs

Tags: codenameone

Toastbar message is added on first form when end time for a control is selected before start time with 4 seconds as timeout. Within 4 seconds if  I correct the time and click the button to navigate to the second form there is no issue. But if I click back command on second form to go to previous form, toast bar message still exists in that form as timeout did n't occur before I click the button. Please advise if there is any way I can dispose that Toastbar message on first form before timeout time occurs when I move to second form early.

Code:
1st Form:

```
  ToastBar.showErrorMessage("End time must be after start date/time of the 
     Activity", 4000);
```

2nd Form:

```
 getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> prev.showBack());
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try messing around with clear(). This is what I'm using:

```
ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
status.setMessage("Message");
status.setExpires(3000);
status.show();
new UITimer(() -> {
    status.clear();
}).schedule(3000, false, this);
```

Comment: That's a good use case. I'll change the static showMessage/Error methods to return a `Status` object that you can clear manually in the next update.

Comment: @Nick I will try this logic  for now.

Comment: @Nick -  If will clear the status, Toastbar still display as empty. I want the toastbar to dispose. clear command not making the toastbar to go away. Please suggest